# how to replace a single key value pair from an object in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, replace, key-value

I have a single object of with key value pair, and i need to replace the first key value pair with a new key value in react.js.
I have tried to make immutable process like

```
const data = {
   firstKey : firstValue,
   secondKey : secondValue,
   thirdKey : thirdValue
}

const newData = {...data, newFirstKey: newFirstValue}
```

but its adding a new key value pair to the object

Comment: You need to use the correct name of the first key it's `firstKey ` not `newFirstKey`. Try `const newData = {...data, firstKey: newFirstValue}`

Comment: Because that's what the code does - it adds a new key/value pair to the object. Maybe just [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) the old property?

Comment: Can you explain what your expected result is instead?

Answer (score 1):

That is expected behavior. See [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) on spreading Objects.

If you want to replace a value you have to use the property name which you want to replace and set the new value.

```js
const data = {
   firstKey : "firstValue",
   secondKey : "secondValue",
   thirdKey : "thirdValue"
}

const newData = {...data, firstKey: "newFirstValue"}
console.log(newData)
```

If you use a new unknown property name, this new property will be added to the object.

```js
const data = {
   firstKey : "firstValue",
   secondKey : "secondValue",
   thirdKey : "thirdValue"
}

const newData = {...data, unknownProperty: "newFirstValue"}
console.log(newData)
```